Sveltekit: 404 Not Found
I am teaching myself Sveltekit and my button is not taking me to the page it's supposed to, instead I get a 404 not Found. The file name in the routes folder is exactly the same as what I passed into the on:click={}
<script>
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
</script>

<header class="sticky top-0 z-30">
  <nav class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex">
          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <a href="/" class="text-2xl font-bold">redis-book</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-700 disabled:bg-gray-300 py-2 px-4 flex justify-center items-center text-white transition ease-in duration-200 text-center text-base font-semibold shadow-md focus:outline-none rounded-full h-8"
            on:click={() => goto('/upload-notebook')}
          >
            <span class="material-icons mr-1" style="font-size:20px;">add</span>
            Upload Notebook
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 disabled:bg-blue-300 py-2 px-4 flex justify-center items-center text-white transition ease-in duration-200 text-center text-base font-semibold shadow-md focus:outline-none rounded-full h-8"
            on:click={() => goto('/new-notebook')}
          >
            <span class="material-icons mr-1" style="font-size:20px;">add</span>
            New Notebook
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

The new-notebook.svelte content is correct:
<script>
  const titles = [
    "My Past Skin Notebook",
    "My Fitting Mine Notebook",
    "My Amazing Journey Notebook",
    "My Adventurous Tale Notebook",
    "My Creative Ideas Notebook"
  ];

  function getRandomTitle() {
    return titles[Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length)];
  }

  let title = getRandomTitle();
</script>

<div class="p-4">
  <div class="bg-gray-100 p-4 rounded shadow">
    <span class="text-xl font-bold">{title}</span>
  </div>
</div>

Vite looks properly configured in svelte.config.js:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
// Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
// for more information about preprocessors
preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

kit: {
    // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
    // If your environment is not supported, or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
    // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
    adapter: adapter()
}
};

export default config;

I cannnot make out why it cannot find the new-notebook.svelte page.

You should not use buttons for navigation, just use links (<a>).

Place the contents of new-notebook.svelte inside src/routes/new-notebook/+page.svelte.
See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-svelte
